# .NET 2.0 application - which Framework to require for maximum portability?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-2.0, installshield

I am continuing development on a C# code base written for .NET 2.0.
The first thing I did was upgrade to Visual Studio 2012, only to discover that this requires upgrading my Setup projects to something called InstallShield Spring 2012 from Flexera Software. One of the head-scratchers this produces is the list of .NET Frameworks it supports: the lowest is 3.5, while 2.0 suffices for my application.

I don't intend to use any post-2.0 .NET features in my code.  I do want to supply installers that will work on the widest possible range of machines.

Can I just assume that whoever can install my application will either have 3.5 SP1 already installed or have no problems with installing it?

If not, i.e. if there is a non-negligible class of prospective users who can install and run my .NET 2.0 application, but cannot or will not install the .NET 3.5 Framework, how can I best support those users?

Comment: Given that the 3.5 is available for XP, the oldest *supported* operating system from Microsoft, you really shouldn't have a problem targeting it... in theory.  In practice, not everyone keeps up on their updates, so you *may* encounter users without 3.5 installed.

Comment: It's fine if it's not installed, as long as they can install it along with my application, if they can install my application in the first place.

Comment: Time has moved on, 8 years is a long time in software engineering.  You are getting a strong hint from your installer that it no longer makes sense to install such an old version of .NET.  3.5SP1 is especially desirable for its small bootstrapper.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think InstallShield gives off that vibe.  InstallShield installers support every type of resource that you can conceive on the Windows platform.  Fat, thin, web, n-Tier, Client/Server, ODBC, Registry, XML, PowerBuilder, VB6 .... it has to do it all.

Comment: @Christopher Painter: Well, to me, someone who isn't an expert on .NET deployment engineering, and has no time to study the subject in the first place, it does, merely by having dropped .NET 2.0 from its list of supported .NET Framework installation requirements.

Comment: I just booted up ISLE and I see the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 redistributable is still shown in the list.  While I don't see .NET 2.0 SP2 is Installed as a predefined System Software Requirement, you can use the Create New Launch Condition Wizard to define it.  Of course that might require you to learn MSI concepts such things as AppSearch and RegLocator.

Comment: @Christopher Painter: It is not in my list, and I have no idea how to learn these concepts in a predictable, budgetable fashion, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: So why bother to upgrade to VS2012 at all?  VS2005, 2008 or 2010 can all develop .NET 2.0 applications and support Visual Studio Deployment Projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues at play here....

If you don't want to give up Visual Studio Deployment projects, but them in their own solution and keep using VS2010 to maintain them.   Or you can switch to InstallShield Limited edition or Windows Installer XML

.NET 2.0 is a decent framework to standardize on but realize that on a Window 7 or Windows 8 machine it might not be installed.  The simplest solution is to compile against .NET 2.0  but use an app.config that specifies the activation policy to enable it to run on .NET 4.0/4.5 (CLR 4.0 ).

Comment: I checked out WiX and it's useless to me: it requires detailed knowledge of how Windows Installers work that I have no time to learn. Yes, switching back to VS2010 is an option (there is plenty more stuff to fix in my new InstallShield setup) but obviously I'd rather use VS 2012.

Comment: Switched back to VS2010 - I wasn't aware that the solution and project file formats haven't changed.